# Array wont iterate properly and check values - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, web-applications

I am using JavaScript to make a little application where the user inputs some numbers and it stores it in an array. The application then prints out 1 to 40 on the screen in green. If any number that is stored in the array is equal to 1 to 40 then when it comes on the screen it will be red not green.

```
var nums = document.getElementById('numbers').value;        
var numArray = [];
numArray = nums.split(" ");

for (n = 1; n < 41; n++) {
    if (n === numArray[n]) {
        document.write('<p>' + n + '</p}><br>');
    }
    else {
        document.write('<p>' + n + ' not in array</p}><br>');
    }
}
```

The code above is just one attempt. I have also tried nested forloops, but that will print 1-40 check if it exists. and then print it out again. until it is done.

So, how can I make it just iterate 1-40 and if it exists in the array print something different on screen? Ive been stuck on this for ages!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Array.indexOf method to search an array for a value. You must also cast the number you are searching for as a string. Here is a working loop:

```
for (n = 1; n < 41; n++) {
    if (numArray.indexOf(n.toString()) >=0) {
        document.write('<p>' + n + '</p}><br>');
    }
    else {
        document.write('<p>' + n + ' not in array</p}><br>');
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks! I had previously tried to use the indexOf method. I must of used it wrong. Thanks for clearing it up! +1!